# Sum in bash outside while read line

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

I'm trying to come up with the sum of lines in `.js` files in a folder. I'm using this in bash:

```bash
sum=0 && find . | grep ".js" | while read -r f; do wc -l $f | awk '{print $1;}'; done;
```

putting the `$sum += $1` inside the `awk` does not work. how am I supposed to do this?

P.S: I'm aware this can be much easier achieve using

```bash
find . -name '*.js' | xargs wc -l
```

I still want the solution to above.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). There are many other issues with your script too including testing the result of an assignment, unnecessary grep, not escaping the metachar in the grep, not anchoring it, not quoting variables, using the wrong quotes.  You're asking for help to implement an approach you should never take.

Comment: "putting the $sum += $1 inside the awk does not work." -- What exactly did you put and where? What happened? What did you expect to happen? Please edit your question to show _exactly_ what you tried to do.

Answer (score 11):

Try this easy and super fast solution:

```bsh
find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

I tried some solutions with `wc` before, but they will have issues with e.g. newline in file names and/or are slow.

Comment: I noticed that it is not really what OP is looking for regarding his last sentence (PS)... but I like the solution so much, I'll leave it here ;-)

Comment: Or given all filenames fit in one exec, just `-exec awk 'END{print NR}' {} +` (one difference: includes any unterminated final lines of files, which `-exec cat {} + | wc -l` doesn't)

Answer (score 5):

bash executes each command of a pipeline in a separate subshell, unless you enable the `lastpipe` shell option

```
# bash requires job control to be disabled for lastpipe setting
set +m
shopt -s lastpipe

declare -i sum=0
find . -name '*.js' -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r name; do
    (( sum += $(wc -l < "$name") ))   # redirect the file into wc for easier output
done
echo $sum
```

---

[Process substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) are handy for dealing with this subshell problem:

```
declare -i sum=0
while IFS= read -d '' -r name; do
    (( sum += $(wc -l < "$name") ))   # redirect the file into wc for easier output
done < <(
    find . -name '*.js' -print0
)
echo $sum
```

However, this makes the program flow harder to read.

Comment: anyway to use this in a single line in bash?

Comment: Add some semicolons and remove newlines. Why does it need to be one line?

Comment: Remember the `IFS=` or it'll fail for file names that start with spaces. Yes, I know it's unlikely but `IFS=` is something we should all use by default and remove when we need to (like quotes around variables) to avoid any surprises.

Comment: Optionally, omit lastpipe and redirect the whiles input?

Answer (score 5):

You want `awk` to do the addition and show the result?

`awk '{sum +=$1} END {print sum}'` should do the trick.

In my library for bash-scripts I do:

```bash
$ find . -type f -name '*.bash' \
| while read -r f ; do wc -l "$f" ; done \
| awk '{sum +=$1} END {print sum}'
```

and get the result `522`

Comment: like this? `sum=0 && find . | grep ".js" | while read -r f; do wc -l $f | awk '{sum +=$1} END {print sum}'; done;` doesn't work

Comment: The `awk`-command goes outside the loop.  Updated my answer to give an example.

Answer (score 1):

## Abstract

#### To count lines in a directory:

```
shopt -s globstar;                      # valid for bash
set -- ./**/*".js"; cat "$@" | wc -l    # for files under `./` directory
```

#### To sum outside a while read loop

```
shopt -s globstar;                                 # valid for bash
set -- ./**/*".js"                                 # for files under `./` directory
wc -l "$@" | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum-=$1}'   # calculate the sum in awk
```

But why would you re-calculate a sum if `wc -l` prints a total on the last line? :

`wc -l "$@" | tail -n 1`

---

## Detail

There are several elements that may be improved:

- The part of `| awk '{print $1;}'` to select only the first field is not necesary if you execute `wc -l <"$f"` instead of `wc -l $f`. The simple redirection (`<`) makes wc receive the file in its standard input and it will have no filename to print. This would reduce the script to:

  find . | grep ".js" | while read -r f; do wc -l <"$f"; done
- There is no need for a grep call if find does the selection:

  find . -name '*.js' | while read -r f; do wc -l <"$f"; done
- A read will remove leading and trailing blank spaces from file names.
- And actually, find could execute the command for each file (implicit loop):

  find . -name '*.js' -exec sh -c 'wc -l <"$1"' foo '{}' \;
- And it is even possible to make one single global call to `wc` instead of one per file.

  find . -name '*.js' -exec sh -c 'cat "$@" | wc -l' foo '{}' +

But the need to re-call the shell to process each filename without any issue with spaces, tabs, newlines or glob characters (*,?,[) indicates that we may solve this directly in the shell if we do not need some find's special resolution of links.

`set -- *.js; cat "$@" | wc -l           # for the present directory`

Or

```
shopt -s globstar;                      # valid for bash
set -- ./**/*".js"; cat "$@" | wc -l    # for files under `./` directory
```

#### Sum outside a while read loop

The question in the title regards this part of your pipe:

```
while read -r f; do wc -l $f …
```

Assuming the list of files is in the argument list (`$@`) (or it could be inside some array as well) as found above, this will print a list of files with the line count as first field:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$@" | while read -r f; do wc -l "$f"; done
12 filea.js
21 fileb.js
```

At this point you could just add a new pipe with awk to select the first field:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$@" | while read -r f; do wc -l "$f"; done | awk '{print $1}'
12
21
```

But you might as well print all in one line with a `+` appended:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$@" | 
> while read -r f; do wc -l "$f"; done | 
> awk '{printf( "%s+",$1)}'
12+21+
```

And, adding a trailing `0`, make bc sum it all:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$@" | 
> while read -r f; do wc -l "$f"; done |
> awk '{printf("%s+",$1)}END{print 0}' |
> bc
33
```

But, as already said, you can avoid the printing of filename with ``` wc -l <"$f"`` and you can convert the newlines to ```+`, then add a`0` and make bc do the calculation:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$@" |
  while read -r f; do wc -l <"$f"; done |
  { tr '\n' '+'; echo 0; } |
  bc

33
```

or make awk calculate the sum:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$@" | 
  while read -r f; do wc -l <"$f"; done | 
  awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'

33
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another bash way to do this:

```
sum=0 && while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do let sum+=$(sed -n "\$=" "${f}"); done < <(find . -name '*.js' -print0 2>/dev/random) && echo "$sum"

find ... -print0 -- prints with null terminated 
            IFS= -- deset IFS 
   read -r -d '' -- -r do not allow backslash escapes, -d '' set delimiter to NULL
   let sum+=(..) -- add up sum of sed $= "$f", $: last line, =: line #
```